# Equivalence books for Bourbaki's Element of Mathematics

Tags: reference-request

I find that the arrangement of basic topics in Bourbaki's book is quite elegant, I want to learn mathematics following this order. But one problem is the books is too old and sometimes too complex for novice. For example, the Vol.1 last chapter, I think it is about category theory, but the terminology is quite different from what we use now.

I find some equivalence books for the series,  Vol.1 - Jech, Set Theory, first n pages & Awodey - Category theory, Vol.2 - Lang, Algebra

The question is, I want some books about topological group and topological vector space at the same level as the Vol 3, Ch. 3-10 and Vol 5. Any recommendation?